# Pre-commit hook to prevent large file commits

Tags: bash, shell, git

I've written the below bash script to run as a pre-commit hook. The intention is to check the git staging area for any files larger than 1mb, and prevent the commit if any are present.

```
#!/bin/sh
too_big() {
    bytez=$(cat "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/$1" | wc -c)
    if [ "$bytez" -gt 1000000 ] ; then
        cat <<EOF
Error: Attempting to commit a file larger than approximately 1mb.
Commiting large files slows jenkins builds, clones, and other operations we'd rather not slow down.
Consider generating, downloading, zipping, etc these files.
Offending file - $1
EOF
        exit 1
    fi
}

# If you want to allow large files to be committed set this variable to true.
allowbigfiles=$(git config --bool hooks.allowbigfiles)

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec 1>&2

if [ "$allowbigfiles" != "true" ]
then
  set -e
  git diff --name-only --cached $1 | while read x; do too_big $x; done
fi
```

Edit:
The final script ended up as part of a library of [client side Git Hooks](https://github.com/rudikershaw/client-git-hooks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although described as a Bash script, this appears to be a portable shell script that can be run by any POSIX-conformant shell.  That's a good thing, as it means we can use a much smaller, leaner shell such as Dash.

If you haven't yet installed `shellcheck`, I recommend you do so (there's also a web version you can try).  It highlights the following:

- Useless `cat` here:

  > ```
  > bytez=$(cat "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/$1" | wc -c)
  > ```

  That can be simplified to

  > ```
  > bytez=$(<"$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/$1" wc -c)
  > ```
- Unquoted expansion of `$1` - we really wanted to write `"$1"` there.
- Unsafe `read x` ought to be `read -r x`
- `$x` is unquoted

Piping the file into `wc` isn't an efficient way to measure size of a file; we could simply use `stat`:

```
bytez=$(stat -c %s "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/$1")
```

And instead of running `git rev-parse` for every file in the changeset, run it once and remember the value in a variable.

<del>The error message should go to the standard error stream</del> (I see the whole script is redirected to `&2`)

It's not obvious why `set -e` is right down inside the `if` - I'd normally put that immediately after the shebang.

Consider also `set -u` to help detect a likely cause of errors.

Spelling: unless you really mean "1 millibit", that should be "1MB".

A suggestion that might fall into the "too cute" category: since `git config --bool` always produces `true` or `false` as output, we can simply execute that as a command:

```
if ! $(git config --bool hooks.allowbigfiles)
then
```

Line-based reading (i.e. `git diff --name-only | while read`) isn't totally robust; there's a `-z` option provided to produce NUL-separated output.  This will require Bash, though, in order to `read -d`.

---

## Improved code

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

too_big() {
    if [ "$(stat -c %s "$toplevel/$1")" -gt 1000000 ] ; then
        cat <<EOF
Error: Attempting to commit a file larger than approximately 1MB.
Commiting large files slows jenkins builds, clones, and other
operations we would rather not slow down.
Consider generating, downloading, zipping, etc these files.
Offending file - $1
EOF
        exit 1
    fi
}

# If you want to allow large files to be committed set this variable to true.
allowbigfiles=$(git config --bool hooks.allowbigfiles)

# Redirect output to stderr.
exec >&2

if ! "$allowbigfiles"
then
    toplevel=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
    git diff --name-only -z --cached "$1" | 
        while IFS= read -d '' -r x; do too_big "$x"; done
fi
```

Comment: Some people can't imagine cuteness in a shell script.  I love putting commands in `if` statements.  This is a fabulous twist.